# Check both existence and modified date of file

Tags: c#

I'm creating a script that uses data pulled from Random.org. I'm having trouble figuring out how to make it work without repeating the file-creation part of the script. What I'm looking to do is create a new file if the file does not exist ***or*** if the file is >24 hours old.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using TrueRNG;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour {
    private Transform TS;
    public int pspeed = 20;
    public static int playerLives = 3;
    public static int score = 0;
    float timer = 0f;
    string trgd = "R:\\trrnd.txt";

    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();

    public GameObject LaserFab; //variable to reference prefab.

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

        TS = transform;

        TS.position = new Vector3(0, -14.78957f, 0); //Spawn point

        if (File.Exists(trgd))
        {
            print("The file exists! Checking time since creation...");
            //Get date from existing file.
            string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(trgd); 
            print(lines[0]);
            DateTime genDate = Convert.ToDateTime(lines[0]);
                //Is existing data more than 1 day old?
                if (genDate.AddDays(1) > DateTime.UtcNow)
                {
                    print("Random data is old, creating new file...");
                }
        //Append the current date and time to the beginning of a new file
File.AppendAllText(trgd, DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("G") + Environment.NewLine);
        while (!TrueRandom.RandInternet.IsAvailableUniform())
        {
        print("Waiting for True RNG/Random.org data...");
        } //End while loop
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {   
                double rn = TrueRandom.RandInternet.Uniform();
                //Append all the Random.org-pulled data to a single String
                sb.AppendLine(rn.ToString());
            } //End for writing loop
        //Write the "truly" random String to a file
        File.WriteAllText(trgd, sb.ToString());
        } //End date check if
    } //End Start

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        TS.Translate(Vector3.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") * pspeed * Time.deltaTime);

        if (TS.position.x>11.25f || TS.position.x<-11.25f) {
            TS.position = new Vector3 (TS.position.x*-1, TS.position.y, TS.position.z);
        }

        //Fire a laser with the Spacebar.
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("space")) {


            //Get pseudo-randomized laser position
            //This works but is not "truly" random. The random data should be pulled from the trgd file
            //float laspo = TrueRandom.RandInternet.Uniform() > 0.5f ? -1.917277f : 1.917277f;

            //Set Laser position
            Vector3 position = new Vector3(TS.position.x/*+laspo*/, TS.position.y+3.50f, TS.position.z);

            //Fire projectile.
            Instantiate(Resources.Load("LaserFab"), position, Quaternion.identity);

        }

        if (Time.time - timer > 0.4f) {
            renderer.enabled = true;
        }

        print ("Lives remaining: " + playerLives + " Score: " + score + " Current playing time: " + "0");
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider collider)
    {
        if (collider.CompareTag ("Enemy")) { //Tag is name of prefab.
            //When the enemy hits the player, destroy the player and the enemy.
            playerLives--;
            renderer.enabled = false;
            timer = Time.time;
        }

        if (playerLives < 1)
            Destroy(this.gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should explain your intent better. You are appending the the file in the middle of the method, and then rewriting it several lines below. Is this intended?

Comment: Creation could be restricted to one time in this scenario. Here you are not showing that part. First please answer the question posed above.

Comment: I've modified the example to include the rest of the script. The script should check for an existing file, if it can't find it OR the date inside the script is older than 24 hours it will create a new one. The random data is to be used later to randomize where the laser is generated (either the left side or the right).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
if (!File.Exists(@"C:\file.txt") || 
        (File.GetCreationTime(@"C:\file.txt") < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1)))
{
    //Recreate file
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a `FileInfo` object and get all this information from that as well:

```
var f = new FileInfo(@"R:\trrnd.txt");

if(!f.Exists || f.CreationTime < DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

You can also use `UTC` times:

```
if(!f.Exists || f.CreationTimeUtc < DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(-1))
{
    //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string trgd = "D:\\trrnd.txt";
if(File.Exists(trgd))
{
    var dt = File.GetCreationTimeUtc(trgd);
    if((dt - DateTime.UtcNow).Hour > 24)
    {
        //Overwrite existing file
        File.WriteAllLines(trgd,"Some new text");
    }
}
else
{
    //append to existing file
    File.AppendAllText(trgd,"Some Text");
}
```